# How to write chunks of data into excel continuously until it reaches the desired limit and generate another excel sheet after row limit exceeds

Tags: node.js, typescript, exceljs

`I am getting the response in lakhs. Let's say the user requested 5 lakhs of records.
Since it is difficult to bring the whole data at once, Iam trying to bring the data in batches and write it to the excel. For the first iteration the first batch data will write to the excel, I don't know how to continue writing the data into the same sheet until it reaches rowLimit.
I kept rowLimit as 200000 records only.
After the rowLimit exceeds in the particular sheet, it should continue writing into the another sheet.
I tried using nodejs, Exceljs, typescript.

Here is the code:

```
         let responseLimit: any = 1000;
         let rowLimit: any = 100000;
        let numSheets = Math.ceil((params.end - params.start) / responseLimit);
      for (let i = 0; i < numSheets; i++) {
          let batchStart = parseInt(start) + (i * parseInt(responseLimit));
          let batchEnd = Math.min(parseInt(start) + ((i + 1) * parseInt(responseLimit)), end);
          let newObj = {
            start: batchStart,
            end: batchEnd,
            objectEnd: objectEnd,
          };
         let batchParams = Object.assign(params, newObj);
         let worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('retailerList_' + sheetNum);
          worksheet.columns = [
                    { header: "RETAILER NAME", key: "retailerName", width: 25 },
                    { header: "RETAILER CODE", key: "retailerCode", width: 25 },
                    ....
                ]
            if (!!rowIndex == batchParams.end) {
                console.log('In first if loop');
                return resolve('');
            } else if (rowIndex <= rowLimit) {
                // Continue writing data on the same sheet
                console.log('In second if loop');
                return resolve({
                    objectEnd: objectEnd,
                    rowIndex: rowIndex,
                    sheetNum: sheetNum
                });
            } else if (rowIndex > rowLimit) {
                rowIndex = 0    
                sheetNum++
                // Continue writing data in the next sheet
                return resolve({
                    objectEnd: objectEnd,
                    rowIndex: rowIndex,
                    sheetNum: sheetNum,
                    worksheet: worksheet
                });
     }
```

Iam not able to write next batch of data into the same sheet. Help me on how to write the data of every iteration into the same sheet until the row limit reaches i kept.`

Comment: Please use universal measurements instead of local words like *lakh*